# How can I use a variable to specify which field to update with arcpy.UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, ms-access

I am writing a script that cycles through several different point shapefiles, finds how many lie within a given area and the writes the outcome to a table in an Access database. I've used an search cursor to look up the point file names, which is then saved to a variable. I'd then like to use this variable to specify which field to update in another table. Here is my code:

```
selection = 1
while selection < 3:
        rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("C:\\MyDB.mdb\\Source_Class_combinations") #opens search cursor on the info table
        for row in rows:
            if row.Order == selection:  
                destfield = row.DestField # extracts the name of the destination field
        del row  
        del rows 
        print "Defining variables..."
        ptfile = str(destfield)+"_lyr"
        rowtoud = "row."+str(destfield) #create the variable with the field to update

        # Process: Select Layer By Location
        print "select by location"
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(ptfile, "INTERSECT", neighfile, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
        count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(ptfile).getOutput(0))
        print "count = " + str(count)

        #Update the number of points selected in the neighbourhoods table
        print "updating count..."
        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor("C:\\MyDB.mdb\\neighbourhoods") 
        for row in rows:
            if row.StudyID == str(neigh):
                rowtoud = count
                rows.updateRow(row)
        del rows
        del row
        selection +=1
```

The selection all seems to work fine, but the table is not updated and no error message is returned. Can I use a variable like this?

I'm using ArcGIS 10, python 2.6, and Access 2007

Thanks, Flo

Comment: ah ha, that works! but I don't think I can accept a comment as an answer to the question, can I? I guess it's a moot point but is there a way that you can make the the other method work?

Comment: I would try debugging by printing your variable out.  Since the variable only stores the string `row.FieldName` I can't imagine why it wouldn't work -- maybe there's a simple error that you didn't catch?  In any case go with what works!

Comment: I did have a line which printed the variable, and it looked fine, but when I ran the script: rowtoud = count, it re-sets the 'rowtoud' variable to the same value as the 'count' variable. anyway, as you say, I'll use the method that works!

Comment: The `row.FieldName = x` method is just a shortcut to `row.setValue("FieldName", x)`, you cannot use a variable for the field with the `row.FieldName` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `setValue(fieldName, object)` [method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) with your field name variable.